# Cakephp 3 pagination using raw sql

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have some questions about Cakephp3 ORM, and what the find() function returns.

So, using a basic find('all'), an object is returned, and to get data from this function, I use

```
foreach()
```

or

```
execute()->fetchAll('assoc')
```

This code, may be used to create pagination.

```
$data = $obj->find('all');
$this->set('paginations', $this->paginate($data));
```

This is a basic example, but pagination correctly configured will work.

However I have code that is generated from a mysql query :

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
//getAllphotos() is a standard mysql query placed in model table.
$all = $conn->execute($data->getAllphotos());
```

Now, this will not work with pagination:

```
$this->set('paginations', $this->paginate(all));
```

So $all cannot be used as parameter for pagination.

Is there a way to convert this to Cakephp paginator like the object, or maybe I need to create another query, as such :

```
$all = $conn->execute($data->getAllphotos());
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the ORM instead of plain SQL. Especially `getAllphotos` doesn't sound like a complicated query...

Comment: I cant because i have data from 2 databases, and associations dont work..

Comment: @user2610146 have you find any solution?

Comment: @user2610146 no solution? :)